# Android Studio Calculator App - Cannot execute method for android:OnClick

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development and have started to build a calculator app. I finished the code and have se all of the buttons and their functions. The code doesn't show any errors and launches the app fine, but when I click a button, it gives me the error: Cannot execute method for android:Onclick. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private BigDecimal a,b,calculation;
private TextView answer;
private Double conv1, conv2, sqrt1, sqrtcalc;
private int power;
private String str, result, sign, str2, pow, sqrt;

public void number (View view) {

    Button button = (Button) view;
    str += button.getText().toString();
    answer.setText(str);
    conv1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
    a = BigDecimal.valueOf(conv1);


}

public void operation (View view) {

    Button button = (Button) view;

    sign = button.getText().toString();
    answer.setText(str + ".");
    str = "";

}

public void Calculation (View view) {

    Button button = (Button) view;
    str2 = answer.getText().toString();
    conv2 = Double.parseDouble(str2);
    b = BigDecimal.valueOf(conv2);

    if (sign.contentEquals("+")) {

        calculation = a.add(b);
        result = calculation.toString();

    } else if (sign.contentEquals("-")) {

        calculation = a.subtract(b);
        result = calculation.toString();

    } else if (sign.contentEquals("X")) {

        calculation = a.multiply(b);
        result = calculation.toString();

    } else if (sign.contentEquals("÷")) {

        a.divide(b);
        result = calculation.toString();

    } else if (sign.contentEquals("x^n")){

        pow = b.toString();
        power = Integer.parseInt(pow);
        calculation = a.pow(power);
        result = calculation.toString();

    } else if (sign.contentEquals("√")) {

        sqrt = a.toString();
        sqrt1 = Double.parseDouble(sqrt);
        sqrtcalc = Math.sqrt(sqrt1);
        result = sqrtcalc.toString();

    } else {


    }

    answer.setText(result);

}

public void Clear (View view) {

    Button button = (Button) view;
    answer.setText("");
    str = "";
    str2 = "";
    result = "";
    pow = "";
    sign = "";
    sqrt = "";

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

}
}
```

This is all of my code, I will not insert the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.tejasmehta.tejascalc.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:text="+"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="operation" />

<Button
    android:text="5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:text="6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:text="-"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="operation" />

<Button
    android:text="8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button14"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:text="7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:text="x "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:onClick="operation" />

<Button
    android:text="9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:text="4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="÷"
    android:onClick="operation" />

<Button
    android:text="."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button20"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    android:onClick="number" />

<Button
    android:text="√"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/button22"
    android:onClick="operation" />

<Button
    android:text="x^n"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button22"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button22"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button22"
    android:id="@+id/button23"
    android:onClick="operation" />

<Button
    android:text="C"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button24"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button23"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button23"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button23"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button23"
    android:onClick="Clear" />

<Button
    android:text="="
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button24"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button24"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button24"
    android:id="@+id/button25"
    android:onClick="Calculation" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the error message:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at 

 android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$ 
DeclaredOnClickListener.onCli
ck(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                  at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller. 
run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at 
 android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$ . 
DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                  at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller. 
run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
string: "null8"
                  at 
 java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString . 
 (FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
                  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                  at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at 

    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller. 
   run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Second Crash:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for 
 android:onClick
                  at 
    android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$ . 
    DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at 
  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                  at 
  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at 
  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller. 
   run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
                  at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
                  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
                  at com.tejasmehta.tejascalc.MainActivity.Calculation(MainActivity.java:52)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Sorry that it is so broad, but I have looked through the oher ones and their solutions did not help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
 str += button.getText().toString();
```

you are adding null with the Button text

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input  string: "null8"

then exception is thrown in this line: `conv1 = Double.parseDouble(str);` because `null8` cannot convert to Double

so check before adding to string:

```
 public void number(View view) {

    String s = "";
    Button button = (Button) view;
    s = button.getText().toString();
    if (s != null && str!=null) {
        str += s;
        answer.setText(str);
    }
    try {
        conv1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
        a = BigDecimal.valueOf(conv1);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, but when I type the number in the calculator, it shows up as null(number), then when I hit the operation and the second number , it crashes. Why?

Comment: i have edited the condition...`if (s != null && str!=null)` ...and post the log of your second crash..

Comment: Posted second crash

Comment: I tried that code out and not the numbers won't show on the textView

Comment: try the edited code....regarding second crash your str2 is empty so conv2 = Double.parseDouble(str2); gives error....add a check whether it is empty or not..

Answer (score 0):

look here are the following problems you have

1- when u used rafsanahmad007's code the if condition is not met that's why no change happened when u pressed on number button .... but why
well, it is because str is null u didn't initialize it so you  must add
this `str = ""` anywhere in your onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method

2- crashes when u press on operation well because str is null and u used it ...
so when u solve 1- then 2- is automatically solved

now you can press number then operation then number all with no crashes

Hope This Helps xD